# Replace text to link that contains accented characters, without replacing the actual characters in jquery

Tags: jquery, replace

I desire to change my simple text to link that contains accented characers, without replacing the actual characters.

For example lets say I have some data from twitter something like:

> x #LoMásLeído #Cristiano costó más que Bale'

Now I am using code:

`var text = "#LoMásLeído #Cristiano costó más que Bale'";
text.replace(/\#(\w+)/g, '<a href="http://twitter.com/hashtag/$1">#$1</a>');`

Now this will change #Cristiano to 
[#Cristiano](http://twitter.com/hashtag/Cristiano).

Though in the same case it breaks #LoMásLeído to [#LoM](http://twitter.com/hashtag/LoM)ásLeído as it will break on á.

> **Note:** I know  that I can replace all accented characters with plain characters (like á with a) first and then can replace this hashtags with links, but the final result will then contain no original accented characters and will look like [LoMasLeido](http://twitter.com/hashtag/LoMasLeido).
>   I want the final result as original text like:
>   [LoMásLeído](http://twitter.com/hashtag/LoM%C3%A1sLe%C3%ADdo)

Ok, I got its implementation done

> Its implementation in beautiful modules of Joomla
>   by [Webkul](http://webkul.com/), looks great, have a look here
>
> - [Latest Tweet](http://joomla30.webkul.com/twitter-display/latest-tweet.html)
> - [Slide Tweet](http://joomla30.webkul.com/twitter-display/slide-tweet.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
var text = "#LoMásLeído #Cristiano costó más que Bale'";
text.replace(/\#(\S+)/g, '<a href="http://twitter.com/hashtag/$1">#$1</a>');
```

It finds everything but whitespace (`\S`) after the `#` character, instead of only digits, underscores and letters a-z (`\w`). A problem might be that it also includes characters like dots, commas or braces. If you really need a full UTF-8 version of `\w` you probably need a library like [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/). See also http://xregexp.com/plugins/

Comment: I was using this for text containing https but again here hashtags needs to be replaced which do not contain  dots, commas or braces. I'll try something.

Comment: Maybe an option that works for you is to specify all characters that you don't want to include, e.g. `/\#([^\s.,:;()[\]{}]+)/g` But you probably have to add a lot more characters there, or choose to only go for the most common ones.

Comment: Yes that would be easy than including the whole library, though I have to make sure of any other characters that might break a hashtag. Ok, I'll wait for for any other specific answer a few more days...then will mark your answer as accepted :)